# Cómo corregir el error no se ha encontrado o cargado la clase principal en Netbeans?

Tags: java, netbeans

tengo una aplicación creada en NetBeans, pero el problema es que cuando doy 'Run File' en la compilación me sale el error 'No se encontró la clase principal' soy nueva en esto así que no se donde puede estar el error, el mensaje es este :

```
  --- exec-maven-plugin:3.0.0:exec (default-cli) @ portfolio-backend ---
Error: no se ha encontrado o cargado la clase principal com.jhajayramori.portfoliobackend.PortfolioBackendApplication
Command execution failed.
org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.executeInternal (DefaultExecutor.java:404)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.execute (DefaultExecutor.java:166)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.executeCommandLine (ExecMojo.java:982)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.executeCommandLine (ExecMojo.java:929)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.execute (ExecMojo.java:457)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2 (MojoExecutor.java:370)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.java:351)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:171)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:163)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:294)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:960)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:293)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:196)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.maven.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start (BootstrapMainStarter.java:47)
    at org.apache.maven.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute (WrapperExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.wrapper.MavenWrapperMain.main (MavenWrapperMain.java:72)
------------------------------------------------------------------------
BUILD FAILURE
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time:  8.815 s
Finished at: 2022-08-04T17:35:40-03:00
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

El archivo pom.xml esta asi:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.2</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.jhajayra-mori</groupId>
<artifactId>portfolio-backend</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
*<name>portfolio-backend</name>
 <description>mi portfolio web</description>
<properties>
    <java.version>8.0.330.2</java.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
            
            
            <dependency>

            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>

            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>

            </dependency>


            <dependency>

            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>

            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>

            <scope>runtime</scope>

            </dependency>


            <dependency>

            <groupId>mysql</groupId>

            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>

            <scope>runtime</scope>

            </dependency>
            
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>
                        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                    </exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
 </build>

</project>*
```

el archivo que hago 'run' es este:

```
package com.jhajayramori.portfoliobackend;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
 public class PortfolioBackendApplication {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(PortfolioBackendApplication.class, args);
   }

}
```

y por ultimo el archivo `application.properties` conexion a la base de datos es este:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.dll-auto=update
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/portfolio?useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```

No se que es lo que nececito solucionar, busque pero no encontre soluciones.

Les quite muchas lineas de codigo porque no me deja publicar la pregunta, pero

Comment: Más triste todavía es haber resuelto la pregunta anterior y borrarla. Pero bueh, ahí te ayudo editando la pregunta para que se pueda leer mejor. A ver si te animas a dejarle algo a los que sufran el mismo problema que tú en el futuro.

Comment: @Alfabravo  la pregunta se cerro, yo no lo hice, y estuve editando para que quedara bien pero me marcaba error igual, gracias

Comment: En el menú *Run > Set Project Configuration > Customize* presiona el botón *Browse* de *Main Class* y selecciona tu clase `PortfolioBackendApplication`.

Comment: @Sal si, ya lo hice pero no funciono eso tampoco

Comment: Si encontraste una solucion, no seria mejor escribir una respuesta, y de paso compartirla con todos?